# Binary Search Tree Complexity based on Values

Tags: c, tree, big-o, binary-search-tree, complexity-theory

I have created a binary search tree in C language, when i am testing my tree, the insertion and search operations take different times to execute. for example, i have two scenarios, inserting random values from 1 to 10000 and inserting sorted values from 1 to 10000. when i insert random values from 1 to 10000 into my BST then it takes less time than inserting sorted values from 1 to 10000 into my BST.
the same for search operation to be executed in my BST it takes less time while i am searching in those random values, but takes too long while searching in sorted values in my BST.
Now, the problem is the time complexity, can anyone explain, how is this handled? what is the time complexity for all four cases?

**Note:** Inserting and searching those sorted values almost take the same time, still searching takes a bit longer!

Comment: You need to post your bst implementation. What you're reporting looks to me that you're getting an unbalanced BST due to sorted value insertion (you'll get a tree with depth = n). This looks more like a linked list than a tree. There are Balanced BST data structures that can accomodate such sorted inserts but it has a rebalance mechanism built-in.

Comment: See this so you know what an unbalanced BST looks like when you insert ordered or semi-ordered values: https://s3.amazonaws.com/hr-challenge-images/24100/1473289501-fe15119ffb-UnbalancedBST.png

Comment: @AlexandreJuma Exactly, i am using Unbalanced BST, this is only a simple BST, if you want i will add the code and test scenarios as well, but the problem is that i do not understand their complexities.

Comment: You just need to know if the value you're searching is either lower, higher or equal to the current node you're checking. Everytime you turn right or left you're bypassing a lot of possible values to analyze because you know for sure that the value you're looking is impossible to exist on the other side of the tree leaf. That's why balanced bst for search, insert and delete is O(log n). Now if you have an unbalanced tree (like when you insert values pre-sorted), you'll only have values to the right or left, so you end up with O(n) in the worst case because you need to check all values

Comment: Check this animation for sorted vs non sorted in unbalanced binary tree [link](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*OmRV7P0YluY2ToRj44jKGA.gif)

Comment: got it somehow, and can i search inside all these random and sorted values, if yes what will be the complexity then for both? i mean what if i just want to know how much does it take to search in all nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't balance the tree, its structure depends on the insertion order, and a "fully unbalanced" binary search tree is equivalent to a sorted linked list.
Thus, the worst case time complexity for your operations is linear in the tree's size, not logarithmic as it would be in a balanced tree.

For instance, if you insert from 1 and incrementing, you'll end up with

```
 1
/\
  2
  /\
    3
    /\
     ...
```

where the right "spine" is a linked list.

Comment: after i have inserted random values to my BST, then i am calling the free function, i mean inserting the second scenario, which is inserting sorted values is completely new BST, i.e these values are not inserted after those random values. now you mean BST constructed from random values will has less depth than BST constructed from sorted values, that is why searching in sorted values in a BST is taking longer. right?

Comment: That's right. If you understand that higher depths require more node check operations, than you understand why it takes longer. With a lower depth you'll need less node checks until you find your value. You need to do a value check at each depth level of your tree. If you have a higher depth, you have more checks, hence more time to perform the search.

Answer (score 0):

Use AVL Tree. It will keep your tree balanced and you will always get search time of log(n)